# I like to suggest this site could adopt Fibonacci challenge to spice things up maybe?

Tags: discussion, challenge

Roughly put a Fibonacci number in mathematics is a series of number whereby each subsequent/following number is the sum of its predecessors... or something like that.

Instead of using a single tag for the fortnightly challenge would it be much better to reuse tag from previous challenge and add to the new challenge?

E.g:

Challenge#78971 ( tag"H" + tag"P")

Challenge#78972 (tag"P" + tag"J")

Challenge# 78973 (tag"J" + tag"A")

My arguments are that our brain excel at recognizing pattern and attempts to associate more than one object or event together, such feat have yet to be surpassed by machine also we could kill two chicken eggs with an asteriod impactor... 1. increase difficulty yet push up our creativity ceiling cap 2. allow a grace period for us to familiarize with each tag and so that but it won't feel like we're rushing, as a saying goes translated crudely from Chinese: knowing the enemy is half a battle won or something like that.

Btw where is the suggestion box?

Comment: I think this is the suggestion box.  It's an interesting idea, I could maybe see it being a "bonus points" thing to the current challenges.  Especially if we get weird combinations, like say Evolution + Economy or Underwater + Moons.

Comment: For a true Fibionacci sequence challenge, we'd have to take the tags from the previous two weeks. Which could just be its own separate challenge. And one I would definitely support, if I weren't already worried about the viability of our current challenges.

Comment: It could be an unofficial part of the challenge. And at the end of the challenge #N, there is, as usual an answer grouping the questions of the given challenge. And maybe as a second answer, the questions combining challenge #N and #N-1. So it could be quite easy to set..?

Comment: Seems like good fun. Do we have a way to randomize the first few pairings, to see what sparks interest?

Comment: We could always start a new challange.